# Create bubble plot in R using satellite map

Tags: r, dictionary, plot, satellite

I already created a bubble plot using the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)

library(sp)

library(raster)

library(maps)

library(mapdata)

library(maptools)

library(gstat)

library(ggmap)

xy <- se_pp[,c("longitude_s", "latitude_s")]

nl <- getData('GADM', country="Netherlands", level=2) #raster data, format SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

# coercing the polygon outlines to a SpatialLines object

spl <- list("sp.lines", as(nl, "SpatialLines"))

SPDF <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=xy, data=se_pp)

projection(SPDF)<- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0"

coordinates(SPDF)[1:5,] #retrieves spatial coordinates form the dataframe

bubble(SPDF, "Quantity", sp.layout=spl, main="Plaice Quantity (#/km2), end summer (Sand Engine)")
```

Now I get a map of the Dutch coast containing the bubble plot (via getData).
Unfortunately this is a very simple map.
I would like to have a satellite map of the same area, which shows more detail, to show my bubble plot. 
Does anyone know if this is possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you still check SO. But, I leave one approach for you. You can play with the values in zoom to identify the best zoom for your purpose. The CRAN manual of `ggmap` offers you more examples. Please have a look.

```
map <- get_map(location = 'netherlands', zoom = 7,
               source = 'google',
               maptype = 'satellite')

ggmap(map)
```