# R Create a Spatial Bubble Plot That Overlays A basemap of the US and other spatial layers as needed

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, ggmap, bubble-chart

I'm trying to produce a nice bubble plot overlaid on top of a basemap of the US (i could import a shapefile if that is preferred but i've been using the R basemaps.

```
library(ggplot2,sp,raster,maps,mapdata,maptools,ggmap,rgeos)
myData = data.frame(name=c("Florida","Colorado","california","Harvard","Yellowstone"),
                lat=c(28.1,39,37,42,44.6), 
                long=c(-81.6,-105.5,-120,-71,-110),
                pop=c(280,156,128,118,202))
```

Using this code below, that i adapted from another stack overflow post ([Create bubble plot in R using satellite map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427479/create-bubble-plot-in-r-using-satellite-map)), i am able to overlay a bubble plot on a map of the US. However this renders very slowly, the extent is too tight, it is bounded in a box, i'm not able to add other layers to the plot from what i can tell, and the base map is thick and not visually clean.

```
xy <- myData[,c("long", "lat")]
nl <- getData('GADM', country="USA", level=1) #raster data, format SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
nl <- gSimplify(nl, tol=0.01, topologyPreserve=TRUE)
# coercing the polygon outlines to a SpatialLines object
spl <- list("sp.lines", as(nl, "SpatialLines"))
SPDF <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=xy, data=myData)
coordinates(myData) <- c("lat", "long")
projection(SPDF)<- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0"
coordinates(SPDF)[1:5,] #retrieves spatial coordinates form the dataframe
bubble(SPDF, "pop", sp.layout=spl, main="This is It!")
```

I can draw a nice basemap using this code. I add points to the map but they are not sized by the pop column in my data. And i can add additional layers to this map. But can i control the size of the points and the symbol itself like i can using a bubble plot?

```
map(database= "world", ylim=c(45,90), 
    xlim=c(-160,-50), col="grey80", 
    fill=TRUE, projection="gilbert", 
    orientation= c(90,0,225))

coord <- mapproject(myData$lon, myData$lat, proj="gilbert",orientation=c(90, 0, 225))
points(coord, pch=20, cex=1.2, col="red")
```

Can anyone please guide me towards the best way to plot a bubble map in R where i can adjust the fill and outline of the symbols in the bubble map, And i can add a clean basemap, that i can a) control the colors of (fill and lines) and b) add additional layers to (for instance another shapefile layer).

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be helpful. I approached your question using my own way. This may be a simpler operation to achieve what you are probably trying to do. For maps, `GADM` is great. But, some packages already got maps. Here, you can easily get the States map in the following way. Then, you can draw the map using `ggplot2`. `geom_path` draws the US, and `geom_point` adds the data points in `myData`.If you want to control size of bubbles in `ggplot2`,you can use `size` in `aes`.

```
library(map)
library(ggplot2)

# Get US map
usa <- map_data("state")

# Draw the map and add the data points in myData

ggplot() +
geom_path(data = usa, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
geom_point(data = myData, aes(x = long, y = lat, size = pop), color = "red")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The following take a similar approach to @jazzurro's use of ggplot and your initial approach, but

- uses a different base map
- further reduces the polygons (you don't need hi-res borders for a bubble plot)
- uses `geom_map` vs `geom_path` or `geom_polygon`
- uses the Albers projection in `coord_map`
- gets rid of map chart junk

```
library(maptools)
library(mapproj)
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)

# for theme_map
devtools::source_gist("33baa3a79c5cfef0f6df")

# nice US map GeoJSON
us <- readOGR(dsn="http://eric.clst.org/wupl/Stuff/gz_2010_us_040_00_500k.json", layer="OGRGeoJSON")

# even smaller polygons
us <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(gSimplify(us, tol=0.1, topologyPreserve=TRUE), 
                               data=us@data)

# don't need these for the continental base map
us <- us[!us$NAME %in% c("Alaska", "Hawaii", "Puerto Rico", "District of Columbia"),]

# for ggplot
map <- fortify(us, region="NAME")

# your data
myData <- data.frame(name=c("Florida", "Colorado", "California", "Harvard", "Yellowstone"),
                     lat=c(28.1, 39, 37, 42, 44.6), 
                     long=c(-81.6, -105.5, -120, -71,-110),
                     pop=c(280, 156, 128, 118, 202))

# the map

gg <- ggplot()
# the base map
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=map, map=map,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id, group=group),
                    fill="#ffffff", color="#0e0e0e", size=0.15)
# your bubbles
gg <- gg + geom_point(data=myData, 
                      aes(x=long, y=lat, size=pop), color="#AD655F") 
gg <- gg + labs(title="Bubbles")
# much better projection for US maps
gg <- gg + coord_map(projection="albers", lat=39, lat1=45)
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position="bottom")
gg <- gg + theme(plot.title=element_text(size=16))
gg
```

[image]

This should make it pretty straightforward to add other layers as well.

Comment: THANK you! this works perfectly and allows me the flexibility to add new layers and manage projection information. The first answer is short and elegant but it started to fall apart when i tried to add other layers. i'll promote it when i have enough reputation to do so :)

Comment: Bit of a problem.  What am I doing wrong?  > us <- readOGR(dsn="http://eric.clst.org/wupl/Stuff/gz_2010_us_040_00_500k.json", layer="OGRGeoJSON")
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
  Cannot open file

Comment: @lawyeR I wonder if `;` right after `.json` is causing the error message.

Comment: I always have something to learn from your gis posts. Thank you for sharing this idea.

Comment: @jazzurro: thanks for the thought but there is no semi-colon in the code I run.  I don't know why the copy and paste in my first comment added it (or I blundered): > us <- readOGR(dsn="http://eric.clst.org/wupl/Stuff/gz_2010_us_040_00_500k.json", layer="OGRGeoJSON")
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
  Cannot open file

Comment: @lawyeR I wonder which OS you have. For mac, I do something like readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "filename without extension"). Depending on OS, you probably specify dsn and layer in different ways, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Can you try downloading the `gz_2010_us_040_00_500k.json` locally (prbly a good idea for "production" anyway) and seeing if that fixes the issue (so switch to a local path). Also, I, too, am seeing the ";" in your pasted code, @lawyeR. I wonder if there isn't an errant invisible byte that's showing up as "`;`" here.

Comment: @lawyeR in case it's an SO markdown rendering bug, I [made a gist](https://gist.github.com/hrbrmstr/a9fbe6036bbe538cdc90) from the code after re-verifying that it works.

Comment: I feel I am being a pest, but I admire @hrbmstr's solutions and want to learn them.  I am on Windows, in case the OS makes a difference.  I retyped the call in the console, to avoid errant invisible gremlins, but got the same error. Are there other arguments I should chg from default? I copied and pasted the gz_etc data from the website into a .csv file but after reading that into R, it is missing a slot: proj4string