# How to add a SpatialPolygons to a bubble plot in R

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sp

I would like to use the function `bubble` from the packge `sp` to plot data and I would like to add a `SpatialPolygons` layer. I can easily plot the data using `spplot` but for some reason it doesn't work with `bubble`. For example:

```
library(sp)
# Create SpatialPolygons
Sr1 <- Polygon(cbind(c(2,4,4,1,2),c(2,3,5,4,2)))
Srs1 <- Polygons(list(Sr1), "s1")
SpP <- SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1))
# Create SpatialPointsDataFrame
pp <- data.frame(x1=2:4,x2=2:4,att=2:4)
coordinates(pp) <- ~x1+x2
# Plot using spplot
spplot(pp, sp.layout=list("sp.polygons", SpP, fill="blue"))
# Plot using bubble
bubble(pp, sp.layout=list("sp.polygons", SpP, fill="blue"))
```

[Some](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23427479/2870670) have done this through transforming the `SpatialPolygons` into `SpatialLines` and it looks like I could do it through ggplot2 (see [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27328564/2870670)), but I'm confused why the bubble plot doesn't work with `SpatialPolygons`. Any trick to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround is to use a custom panel function:

```
bubble(pp, "att",
       panel=function(...) {
         sp.polygons(SpP, fill="blue")
         sp:::panel.bubble(...)
       })
```

[image: bubble]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your `spplot`s aren't working but this is right up `ggplot`'s alley:

```
library(sp)
library(ggplot2)

Sr1 <- Polygon(cbind(c(2,4,4,1,2),c(2,3,5,4,2)))
Srs1 <- Polygons(list(Sr1), "s1")
SpP <- SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1))

pp <- data.frame(x1=2:4,x2=2:4,att=2:4)

spdf <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SpP, data=data.frame(row.names="s1", val=1))
sp_map <- fortify(spdf)

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=sp_map, map=sp_map,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id), 
                    color="black", fill="blue")
gg <- gg + geom_point(data=pp, aes(x=x1, y=x2, size=att), color="orange")
gg <- gg + scale_size_continuous(range=c(5,10))
gg <- gg + coord_equal(ylim=c(1.5,5), xlim=c(1,4.5))
gg <- gg + labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg <- gg + theme(panel.grid=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(panel.border=element_blank())
gg
```

[image]

(I might have mixed up which is x & y for the bubbles)

You have (IMO) much better control over aesthetics this way.